# Unsolvable enigmatic 3x3x3 Rubik's cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube

Haven't seen this problem on any other video or blog post; need help if you feel up to the challenge.

So I have finished the 3x3x3 Rubik's cube using the F2L method ... except the top player two corners next to each other, i.e. the front left and right are on the wrong sides. I know how to solve the corner placement with (URU'L'URU'L), but no matter the repeats I'm always left with two corners not in correct placement.

This is a very early version of the cube from the 80's, and seems it cannot be taken apart despite trying via videos on how to do so. I've done corner to opposite corner moves as well as a mirror edge of it (turn cube clockwise U'L'UR U'LUR'), but it seems the cube must be a faulty one?
Unless someone can figure out an algorithm, because I sure can't.

However, I have not seen this scenario anywhere.

Bird's eye view: here my cube so F2L white on the bottom, going clockwise For cube is green, R=orange B=yellow L=dark red, D=white, Top = blue centre cross matched up on all sides with bottom right side fully placed and positioned with blue on top, F is Green, Right is Orange, Front Left Corner has U=Orange, F=blue, L=yellow, Right back 3rd layer is U=Green, R dark red, B=Blue, and far left is U=yellow, L=blue, B=Dark Red

I hope you could help me figure out an algorithm, or is this a dodgy cube? I definitely can't get the pieces out despite attempts; it's one of the heavy old ones with stickers on but they won't stick back on if I were to try to pull them off they'd probably rip. Help needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you maybe add some photos, or at least improve your description of the state of your cube? It is hard to figure out exactly what you mean, and if I do understand correctly the corner at UBR is the mirror image from what it should be. That said, it is mathematically impossible to swap two corners while also leaving all the edges in place. If pieces cannot be popped out, what could have happened is that the centre caps were taken off and replaced incorrectly. If you cycle the middle layer centre caps R->F->L->B->R, it should become solvable again.

Answer (score 1):

If your last two corner pieces are in the right locations on the cube, but the wrong orientation, you can solve the cube by repeating R' D' R D [like this](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/how-to-solve-the-rubiks-cube-beginners-method/orient-yellow-corners-how-to-solve-last-layer-corner/).

If your last two corner pieces are swapped, you're out of luck. Someone has disassembled and reassembled your cube into an unsolvable configuration.